# FirebaseCloudMessaging : PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notifications from an Node.js API to a Flutter application.
First, I want to make my application able to receive notifications from Firebase.

But, when I initializeApp, I got an issue :

> PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform
> returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))

and this, in the console:

```
E/flutter (25357): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (25357): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:250)
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1
E/flutter (25357): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25357): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89)
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:1
E/flutter (25357): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25357): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40)
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:1
E/flutter (25357): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25357): #3      main (package:notifappfcm/main.dart:13)
package:notifappfcm/main.dart:1
```

I've been looking for a solution to this problem, but I really can't find it.

This is my application code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'mainscreen.dart';

Future<void> _firebadeMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // options: DefaultFirebaseConfig.platformOptions
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebadeMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

 
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mainscreen.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    requestPermission();
    loadFCM();
    listenFCM();
    // Get device's notification token
    getToken();
  }


  void getToken() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token) => print(token));
  }

  void requestPermission() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }

  void listenFCM() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                    // ignore: todo
                    // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android (now using one that already exists)
                    icon: 'launch_background')));
      }
    });
  }

  void loadFCM() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        importance: Importance.high,
        enableVibration: true,
      );

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
      ///
      /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
      /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

      /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
      /// heads up notifications.
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I found an issue, I just had to proprely link my application with firebase.
It was wrong when I did it the first time.
This is a link you can follow to help you link your application and your FCM :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

PS : follow the full tutorial, i didn't at the very first time and this is why i get errors ^^

Comment: What do you mean by properly link . Can you be more specific

Comment: To make your application able to communicate with Firebase, u have to register your app in Firebase.
So, I folloed the entier tutorial on firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android and my code was working after it.
The mistake I've done was to only do the first part of the tutorial (didn't see the next ones), and my application wasn't linked with Firebase.

Comment: Inn my case ,I do flutter clean and its working fine

Comment: @Shiroe did you have any idea as to why credentials are being duplicated? One is to be found in google-services.json and the other in their generated dart files.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make sure you have added the Firebase SDK dependencies in the
Project Level **build.gradle** file
and Application Level **build.gradle** file

Dependencies to be added in Project Level **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    ...
  }
}
```

Dependencies to be added in App Level **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')

  // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
```

Comment: Looks like the flutter project setup on Firebase doesn't add this dependencies by default.

Comment: I did all this and I am still facing the error

Answer (score 45):

Attention. Manually changing build.gradle files as described above is not a solution. It will either won't work or every build will generate lots of warnings as using deprecated dependencies. Correct solution is this:
Firebase should be intialized like below:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

For this, you will need to run some commands from command line / terminal:

```
// Add firebase core into your project
flutter pub add firebase_core
// Generate firebase options file
flutterfire configure
```

And then you need to import these ones inside your .dart file:

```
// Import firebase core and generated file
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

For details you can refer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#:%7E:text=From%20your%20Flutter%20project%20directory%2C%20run%20the%20following%20command%20to%20install,flutter%20run).

Comment: I was missing `options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform` in my `Firebase.initializeApp` in my main() function in main.dart. After adding this (and importing the `firebase_options.dart` file that gets created with `flutterfire configure` in the terminal), it worked.

Comment: All of the above solutions for modifying `build.gradle` did not work for me. However, this solution of adding `options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform` inside `Firebase.initializeApp` worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I was having the same exception and this beautiful solution worked.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: You are bang on!!!

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you have these settings in your `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

And then in your `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

You can follow the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file)

And don't forget to download google-service.json from firebase project console, and put it into android/app folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32468233)

Comment: @Lalaluka Thanks for reminding. I've modified.

Answer (score 10):

From:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

To:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Works for me!

Comment: How dis we get DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform I am not able to find that. Could you please help me?

Comment: @RohitSharma follow this instruction https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android, after you do `flutterfire configure` it will generate the necessary file such as lib/firebase_options.dart etc

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes FlutterFire cli is not able to update build.gradle files so you get the above error

in project level build.gradle add the firebase dependencies as

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
}
```

in app level build.gradle file apply firebase plugins as

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 6):

I have changed classpath from classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0` to classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15` and worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. It works, But why?. Can you explain it?

Comment: This worked for me. 4.4.0 introduces a breaking change. I would like to know exactly, what is happening and would love a migration guide.

Answer (score 5):

Similarly like any other answers here. You'll have to setup the necessary dependencies manually, especially since both our `build.gradle` (Project level & App level) doesn't have any direct changes after integrating our Flutter app with Firebase.

Here's a brief step to troubleshoots your issues.

Go To your Project-level `build.gradle` And add this following line within the file dependencies.

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13' // Add this line
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Afterwards, Go to your App-level `build.gradle` and add these lines as well.

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

This will ensure our Firebase is ready for development.

Of course. Even if you've added these lines or had already configured it, there might be error that still persist. Most commonly is:

```
E/flutter (10040): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] 
Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
E/flutter (10040): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.app 
(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:149:5)
E/flutter (10040): #1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:55:41)
E/flutter (10040): #2      FirebaseMessaging.instance (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:32:47)
```

For whatever reason,

> Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call `Firebase.initializeApp()`

Error is also tied with:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

On your case as well. Though, there's a solution that fixed the problem is by simply adding `DefaultFirebaseOptions` when we initialize the app.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform // Add thiis.
);
```

Answer (score 3):

For me nothing work from above but changing the version from `4.4.0` to `4.3.13` in project level build.gradle file/

From

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to set the DefaultFirebaseOptions in `await Firebase.initializeApp();` line.

According to this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#initialize-firebase), you need to put the options.

Follow this step by step

1. Run `flutter pub add firebase_core`
2. Run `flutterfire configure`. Skip this if you already configure your project.
3. In your `main.dart`, update this in your code.

From

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

To

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

4. Try running your application

I hope this helps to solve this issue.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 2):

This Solution is effective :)

in project level build.gradle add the firebase dependencies as

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
}
```

in app level build.gradle file apply firebase plugins as

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer still definitely works, but it requires manual operations plus the uncertainty of which Google Services version and Firebase BOM to add.

I recommend using the **FlutterFire CLI** to configure the project and to automatically set up all these **build.gradle** dependencies.

[Official configuration setup can be found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android).

Answer (score 1):

In my case these two lines were missing from app/build.gardle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring flutter in ios make sure to initilize this in swift file
FirebaseApp.configure()

import FirebaseCore //import this on top

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to solved this issue, I checked the registration app process and  I have missed to add this line:

at the level app's  build.grade:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I added this dependencies too:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx' for authentication.

Regards.

Jesus

Answer (score 0):

I had both my Ethernet and WiFi connected. What solved it for me was to disconnect my Ethernet cable and only use WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

After long search I found appropriate solution for me (the same issue):
simple you need "to connect" your project to firebase.

**Try this from step 1 - 3:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

I'll be glad if it's useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

add this Line in the Main. dart File

in Main Function
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One**

you want to upgrade to the latest version. So I used the following:

```
flutter channel dev
```

Comment: post this in the comments as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "ApiKey",
      appId: "AppId",
      messagingSenderId: "MessagingSenderId",
      projectId: "ProjectId",
    ),
  );
```

Enter your values from `google-services.json`...

```js
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB9kC9vjrAyO5u4VyXsHksVTnumR656YIE",
    appId: "1:7614635480:android:7bb656cfb5960e79a866ad",
    messagingSenderId: "7614635480",
    projectId: "notificatonpush",
  )
);
```

Comment: Please add a description of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my modified main function below, which resolved the problem for me:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'your_api_key',  //Replace with API key from google-services.json
        appId: 'your_app_id',    // Replace with App ID from google-services.json`enter code here`
        messagingSenderId: 'your_messaging_sender_id',  // Replace with Messaging Sender ID from google-services.json
        projectId: 'your_project_id',  // Replace with Project ID from google-services.json
      ),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Platform.isAndroid?
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "ApiKey",
      appId: "AppId",
      messagingSenderId: "MessagingSenderId",
      projectId: "ProjectId",
    ),
  );
: Firebase.initializeApp();
```

For "**Platform.isAndroid**" import "**import dart:io**'";

Now enter the above values from google-services.json

[Api key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLyY.png)

[AppId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4722.png)

[Project number is messagingSenderId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiXHN.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Platform.isAndroid
    ? await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "ApiKey",
        appId: "ApiID",
        messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
        projectId: "projectId",
      ),
    )
    : await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

The values of:

```
ApiKey: current_key
ApiId: mobilesdk_app_id
messagingSenderId: Project_number
projectId: project_id
```

Are found in the `google_services.json` file uploaded to app module

Answer (score 0):

It could occur because no `Firebase Firestore`, `Authentication`, or `any other product` you're using is `created`.

Like you are using `Firestore`, but haven't `created/enabled` it in `Firebase Console.`

I was facing this `error` for the ***reasons mentioned above!***

Answer (score 0):

**If Everything you tried above and didnot workout then Follow me**

Just create a new flutter project in different folder with same name. 
And copy all the files i,e Lib\ folder and add all package to the pubspec.yaml 
 Then copy google_services.json and respective classpath and plugins and you are ready to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

exception has occurred. platformexception (platformexception(null-error, host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))

For me, it worked by **running the app without debugging mode**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).