# Splash screen stuck and never shows the main.dart Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, splash-screen

After running my app, it's showing the splash screen and never goes away. Even if I close & reboot the app and even I run the `flutter run` by `Flutter run lib/main.dart` is showing nothing only but the splash screen , I also added the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` but still nothing is working for me. trying everything like `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get` I haven't use any package for the splash-screen. plz can anyone identify the problem would appriciated.
I've added my `terminal` below after launching the app.

Thanks again.

```
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18992): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
E/flutter (18992): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (18992): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:246:7)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #3      main (package:pdfscanner/main.dart:7:3)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992):
```

my `main.dart` looks like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Document Scanner",
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

this is my `build.gradle` in android mainstream

```
   buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What platform are you running your app on, and what's your main.dart code look like?

Comment: Please check if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p

Comment: @TarHalda I've added the main.dart plz check now

Comment: I think the problem is in firebase configuration. Please try to recheck all the steps of firebase configs.

Comment: @MouBiswas I agree with Zakaria and kforjan that it is probably an issue with your Android.gradle or your firebase configuration.

Comment: If you are able to solve it, please post an answer detailing what you did that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here for the 1st error on the `terminal` says

```
A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. 
See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
```

this was solved by removing `<meta-data/>` snippet on `AndroidManifest.xml` , which is :

```
          <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
          <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@mipmap/launch_image" 
              />
```

and for these part of `error` on `terminal` , which is :

```
E/flutter (18992): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:246:7)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992): #3      main (package:pdfscanner/main.dart:7:3)
E/flutter (18992): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18992):
```

I just have to remove

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

which is right after the line

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

on `main.dart` , and by doing so I can see my main `home_page.dart` again. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

adding this on the `app` level `build.gradle` with definitely solve the problem.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15"   // this makes all the difference
}
```