# I got error when i try using firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1911 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (25041): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (25041): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter (25041): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25041): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (25041): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25041): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (25041): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25041): #3      main (package:nota/main.dart:15:3)
E/flutter (25041): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25041):
```

---

i tried many solution like make anew app and connect it with firebase again and another one to connect as flutter project and tried to connect as android but every time o got that same error
this is project GitHub link:
https://github.com/A7medMajed16/Nota_App_Using_Flutter

Comment: I guess this is a repeated question. You can maybe look here for the answer: [FirebaseCloudMessaging : PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p)

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Rather than post a link to your code, you should post it in the question - preferably as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to connect Firebase and Flutter, in case you missed some steps.

1. Install google-services.json file from the firebase project and place it inside the android/app directory.
2. In the android/build.gradle file, paste this code in the buildscript dependencies.

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'`

3. Add the plugin flutterfire_cli in your project,  then in command prompt run `flutterfire configure`. Then it will ask you to select the firebase project and create a file called firebase_options.dart. You can move this file to anywhere you want within your lib folder.
4. In main.dart file,  paste this code into the main() function before the class. Note that you have to import the firebase_options.dart file in order to use this code.

```
    Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "firebase-project",
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
    ).whenComplete((){
      debugPrint('Completed initialization to Firebase');
    });
```

5. Rerun your flutter app. The message should be printed if firebase is successful initialized.