# Error while initializing Firebase for my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to connect my app to firebase, It ran fine until I changed my main.dart files's to

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Please help, I am stuck here since 3 days
I've tried reconnecting to firebase from scratch twice watching different youtube videos , but  still I am unable to connect

The error which I am getting:

```
E/flutter ( 6526): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter ( 6526): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter ( 6526): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6526): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:107:9)
E/flutter ( 6526): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6526): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 6526): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6526): #3      main (package:electralink/main.dart:11:3)
E/flutter ( 6526): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6526):
```

Answer (score 1):

use this for init firebase

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options:DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
 runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It says class DefaultFirebaseOptions is not defined.

Comment: you must have file called
firebase_options.dart
in app route if dont found it user firbase cli to generate file
open firbase console and press in add app select flutter and then follow the instructor to add this file

Answer (score 0):

we don't use "future" main()
try this...

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(const MyApp());
```

}

Comment: Gives the same error as before, I also tried just main but still doesn't work.

Comment: did you do "flutter clean"? or "dart pub cache clean"?
did you make firebase project at firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in main and make sure you have configure and added google play service.json and googleplay service.infoPlist

```
Future<void> init() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //Add this line
    
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
      
    }
```

add to android/build gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    
}
```

add to android/app/buildgradle at the end of it

```
dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

flutter. clean and run

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question days ago. Give it a try. It works for me.

[I got error when i try using firebase with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591551/i-got-error-when-i-try-using-firebase-with-flutter/77610480#77610480)

Answer (score 0):

Okay Guys I found out a way to fix this:
Apparantly the problem was with google gms vesrion:
This is what Firebase website was showing to add:

````
    ```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'```
````

Had to modify it to:

````
    ```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'```
````

And it started working