# Issue in firebase.initializeApp() while running the flutter app project

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-emulator, runtime-error, flutter-dependencies

I am making a ecommerce application using dart and flutter along with firebase for the storage purpose. i have made the entire frontend but facing issue in the firebase connection. i have made the firebase project and downloaded the json file and placed in the /app folder also added the sdk in the build.gradle files. while running the main.dart file i have mentioned an await before the firebase.initializeApp() to check the connection with the firebase but found that it is not connecting with the firebase. the error is:

Error: Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.10.0/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:255:11
options != null
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."

I have tried by upgrading and updating all the firebase_core, firebase_auth version but still it giving me error.
Also i have tried the solutions suggested by the chatgpt such as
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade

Comment: you have to setup configuration for web platform, otherwise error will not fixed,

Comment: how can i do that pls can you guide me @MahmoudSaleh

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web?

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate Flutter and Firebase, you will need the `flutterfire_cli` package and generate the `firebase_options.dart` file, which is most likely what's missing from your initialization code.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591551/i-got-error-when-i-try-using-firebase-with-flutter/77610480#77610480).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same thing. Previous answer was helpful but didn't fix it for me. The comment from @Frank was very helpful. I did as stated below,

From your Flutter project directory, run the following command to ensure that your Flutter app's Firebase configuration is up-to-date:

```
flutterfire configure -- <project name in FB console>
```

In your lib/main.dart file, import the Firebase core plugin and the configuration file you generated earlier:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

Also in your lib/main.dart file, initialize Firebase using the DefaultFirebaseOptions object exported by the configuration file:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Rebuild your Flutter application:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Feel free to replace chrome with your web browser. My lib/main.dart looks like following,

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```