# Firebase Unhandle Exception PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

Tags: javascript, java, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I was make application for user signup and signin by using firebase but I cannot run as properly it give some error like bellow.

```
E/flutter ( 6840): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter ( 6840): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6840): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 6840): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6840): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 6840): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6840): #3      main (package:firebaseapp/main.dart:6:3)
E/flutter ( 6840): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6840):
```

Look at my build.gradle(app)

```
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
        id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    }
    
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
        namespace "com.example.firebaseapp"
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.firebaseapp"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
    
    
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {}
```

and bellow code is my build.gradle(android)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and also I added my main.dart here,

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and this is my pubspec.yaml,

[image]

I was tried all asnwers of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p)  question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it,

First I added bellow implementation in my build.gradle in app level,

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
}
```

and I updated my dependency in project level build.gradle, from classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'`

then I solved that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

please check your SHA key of system(MAC and Windows) is added in this project on firebase because sometime it's through the error regarding SHA key.