# Flutter exeption: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

"I recently initiated a Flutter project and encountered numerous challenges upon integrating it with Firebase.

I diligently addressed each issue until reaching a point where none of the solutions seem to take effect.

I suspect there might be alterations in the overall configuration of build.gradle files (both project-level and app-level).

**This is the error I face:**

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
```

**build.gradle (Project level)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (App level)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.renting_cars"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Many solutions were connected to the `kotlin_version`, and I tried many versions but got the same result!!!

Seeking guidance on resolving this specific issue. Appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? And after doing what are you facing this issue?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I mentioned the problem that I face in the title of the question

Comment: I already faced this issue and I ask here so finally I fix that goto here using this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/77671079/20521312

Comment: @DhanushaDilshan I've tried it, but without any progress, the same for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by doing downgrading for `com.google.gms:google-services:` from `4.4.0` to `4.3.13`,

upgrading the `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:` from `7.2.2` to `8.0.2`,

and finally keeping `ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'` as it is.