# Cant add firebase to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have initialized my firebase in void main

```
  void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

but after I run in my android it goes to white screen and have this error in log cat

```
    E/flutter (24605): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (24605): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter (24605): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24605): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (24605): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24605): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (24605): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24605): #3      main (package:autofarm/main.dart:9:3)
E/flutter (24605): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24605): 
I/zygote  (24605): Do partial code cache collection, code=44KB, data=62KB
I/zygote  (24605): After code cache collection, code=44KB, data=62KB
I/zygote  (24605): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

I already put my json in android gradle, and already add plugin in it. How do I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FirebaseCloudMessaging : PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p)