# PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)) part 2

Tags: flutter, dart

This issue returned after updating to flutter 3.19.0. According to the most voted solution posted by the user @Darsh Shah at [FirebaseCloudMessaging : PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p), one must make sure that the following block exists inside `./android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    ...
  }
}
```

However, according to new flutter's documentation on breaking changes, there is now a new section called "Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins" at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

According to this new documentation, it is now a requirement to completely remove the buildscript section as part of the new migration process, leading to the comeback of this previously solved issue.

How can this issue be solved on flutter 3.19.0?