# Cant connect Flutter to Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, mobile-development

So firstly, i have spend alot of time to connect the Flutter the Firebase, I'm not getting the previous errors but also i dont know if its connected or not. First the errors was in build.gradle file. That has been solved i guess. Now its showing "Skipped XX Frames: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

I'm providing all the necessary code. I hope it can be fixed, i'm on it for so many days.

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:ableeasefinale/pages/UI/parentPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'theme/theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: const ParentPage(),
  theme: lightMode,
  darkTheme: darkMode,
  themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
    );
  }
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
}
```

}

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
plugins{
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}    
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2')
}
```

**Debug Console**
[image: Debug Console after running]

In the last run, debug was also showing following message: 'Skipped XX Frames: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.'

If someone knows a better tutorial to connect it, please provide, it will be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FirebaseCloudMessaging : PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72895721/firebasecloudmessaging-platformexception-platformexceptionnull-error-host-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add FirebaseOptions in main() when initializing firebase:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "ApiKey",
      appId: "AppId",
      messagingSenderId: "MessagingSenderId",
      projectId: "ProjectId",
    ),
  );
```

better approach would be to reconfigure the firebase to your project using [FlutterFire Cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup), it will generate firebase_options.dart file according to your selected platform:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in `main()`:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "ApiKey",
    appId: "AppId",
    messagingSenderId: "MessagingSenderId",
    projectId: "ProjectId",
  ),
);
```