# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Getting this error when running a flutter app:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

I tried doing the following, but nothing worked:

1. `Flutter clean`
2. Invalidated caches
3. Restarted Android Studio
4. Ran `pub get`

The app gets stalled on the splash screen and nothing happens visually on the screen. The terminal shows the error in the title and this is the stack trace:

```
E/flutter (18297): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter (18297): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18297): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (18297): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18297): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (18297): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18297): #3      main (package:myapp/main.dart:16:3)
E/flutter (18297): <asynchronous suspension>
```

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FirebaseHelper.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<ModelAuthUser?>.value(value: AuthService().user, initialData: null),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>(create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),)
        ],
        child: GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'myApp',
          initialRoute: '/home',
          getPages: [
            GetPage(name: '/home', page: () => const Wrapper()),
            GetPage(name: '/notifications', page: () => const ScreenNotifications()),
          ],
        ),
    );

  }
}
```

**firebaseHelper.dart:**

```
class FirebaseHelper {
  //...
    
  static final FirebaseHelper _singleton = FirebaseHelper._internal();

  factory FirebaseHelper() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  FirebaseHelper._internal();

  // To Initialize Firebase
  static Future<void> init() async {
    _firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await _initCloudMessaging();
  }
  
  //...

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78031946/21590733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this in main function:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "ApiKey",
    appId: "AppId",
    messagingSenderId: "MessagingSenderId",
    projectId: "ProjectId",
  ),
);
```

If your project using **FlutterFire CLI**, it will generate **firebase_options.dart** file according to your selected platform:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Do you mind upvoting my question so that this answer can help others in the future?

Comment: This is working from My side. Thank you for support.

Comment: @Dhruvil, I appreciate your response. It provides a straightforward and accessible explanation of how to initialize Firebase in a Flutter project. Thanks!

Comment: That is usefull for me